# List indices must be interegers (slit.function)

Tags: python-3.x, string

Im trying to do a simple program. Is any of these words [a,an,the] appears in my string i should obtain the number of times it ocurrers.

I've already created a list and i split my string . But when i try to access the element in my list it gives the error : list indices must be integers, not str. I know were the problem is-> if v[i] in string.split(). It should be if i in string.split()..  However the i refers to the position and i want to compare what's in the position v[i].

```
v=['a','an','the']
def contain():
    global count
    count=0
    string=input('Digit your string\n')
    for i in v:
        if v[i] in string.split():
            count=count+1
    return count
print(contain())
```

Comment: `if i in string.split():
`?

Answer (score 1):

You are already iterating over the elements.

`for e in v` is similar to `for i in range(len(v)): e = v[i]`

Comment: for i in v is the same as for i in len(v), That i understand but i want to compare a given element in my list v and i call it by saying v[i] and not i.   Is that the part i dont understand

Comment: Then you need the indexes @Luismaia1994 for than iterate over `range(len(v))`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in v: # gaves you : i ='a', i='an', i='the'
    if v[i] in string.split(): #  v['the'] you are trying to get item from v but you are providing string instead of index ex: v['the']
```

because of that you need:

```
    for i in range(len(v)):  # gaves you : i =0, i=1, i=2
       if v[i] in string.split(): # v[0], v[1], where v[0] is 'a' ...
           count=count+1
```

or :

```
v=['a','an','the']
def contain():
    global count
    count=0
    string=input('Digit your string\n')
    for i in v: # i ='a', i='an', i='the'
        if i in string.split(): # now you have:  if 'a' in string.split():
            count=count+1
    return count
```